# Figure of speech: Repeated synonyms

Tags: figures-of-speech

I am looking for the name of the figure of speech,  where two words with similar meaning are used together to convey an idea more emphatically. For example: 'Cease and Desist', 'Null and void',  etc.

I tried googling but nothing concrete turns up.

Thanks.

Comment: I have heard them referred to as couplets, two words coupled together in a common phrase. But couplet has a more common meaning for rhyming lines in poetry.

Answer (score 1):

Pleonasm

According to wiki - Pleonasm is the use of more words or parts of words than is necessary for clear expression: examples are black darkness, or burning fire

Comment: That applies to null and void. But cease and desist are completely different. Both are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have the choice between tautology, accumulatio, hendiadys and pleonasm.
See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_rhetorical_terms

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a classical (Latin or Greek) rhetorical figure, but the following might help.

***Siamese Twins*** are, according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_(linguistics)), "a pair or grouping of words used together as an idiomatic expression or collocation, usually conjoined by the words *and* or *or*."

Wiki has a whole list of Siamese Twins which involve related and synonymous words, so you might think to call such pairs ***Siamese Synonyms*** or ***Related Twins***.

You might like these terms better than *pleonasm*, since they suggest the presence of a conjunctive element where *pleonasm* does not.